# how to merge Objective-c and Swift delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm new to Swift and i would be glad if anyone could help me to merge those two delegete written in two different languages. This is my problem:

ZZAppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ZZAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property(strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end
```

ZZAppDelegate.m:

```
#import "ZZAppDelegate.h"
#import "PayPalMobile.h"

@implementation ZZAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


[PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction :@"TEST",PayPalEnvironmentSandbox :@"TEST"}];
  return YES;
}

@end
```

Both in Obj-C. I have to put them inside this AppDelegate.swift method:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow? 

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool     
{
      .
      .
      .

return true
}
```

If i try to move this (i wrote this in swift):

```
PayPalMobile.initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments(PayPalEnvironmentProduction:"TEST", PayPalEnvironmentSandbox:"TEST")
```

into my AppDelegate.swift method i get this error:

```
Extra argument 'PayPalEnvironmentSandbox' in call.
```

This is the description about that method:

```
/// For example,
///  @{PayPalEnvironmentProduction : @"my-client-id-for-Production",
///    PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"my-client-id-for-Sandbox"}
+ (void)initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:(NSDictionary *)clientIdsForEnvironments;
```

Also, if i remove this extra argument i get this error:

```
Cannot convert the expression's type (PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: StringLiteralConvertible)' to type 'StringLiteralConvertible'
```

About this, i read into another question that: "Objective-C automatically promoted variables, Swift does not."

PS:
I got two bridging header files, one with #import "PayPalMobile.h" and another one (for parse) with #import Bolts/Bolts.h .

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift

Comment: You need to provide an `NSDictionary` to the method - not two separate arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Note the `@{}` in this call: `initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments: @{ PayPalEnvironmentProduction :@"TEST",PayPalEnvironmentSandbox :@"TEST" }`

That's an ObjC `NSDictionary` literal, not the parameters to the method. (Note also that the declaration of `initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments` that you quoted says its parameter is a dictionary.) You're trying to pass those things as parameters, when you should be constructing a (Swift) `Dictionary` literal instead — note the `[]`:

```
PayPalMobile.initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments([PayPalEnvironmentProduction:"TEST", PayPalEnvironmentSandbox:"TEST"])
```

Comment: Thanks for reply rickster ! With those [ ] now seems to work but as @Craig Otis sayd, i need to provide a NSDictionary too right? Because now it gives me an "unwrapping an optional value" error probably provided by this nsdictionary miss.

Comment: An `NSDictionary` in ObjC maps to an `[ NSObject: AnyObject ]` in Swift, and that's what the brackets provide. However, `PayPalEnvironmentProduction` may import as an optional, so you might need to unwrap it. Option-click it (and/or the `initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments` call) in Xcode to see their Swiftified declarations to be sure.

Comment: If i option-click on Production it give me this: [link] (http://prntscr.com/66w87r), and for initialize: [link] (http://prntscr.com/66w8qc). I'll post here what should be the right result into the console: Environment: Optional("sandbox"). Accept credit cards? Optional(true) and this is what it gives to me: Environment: nil. Accept credit cards? nil
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. But i can't understand why this error, i only moved from ZZAppDelegate.m the code into AppDelegate.swift and ain't touch anything else from the standard paypal code.